# What is this and why is it so important $(x,y) \to (y,x)$?

Tags: notation, reflection

When doing a $y=x$ reflection the notation is $(x,y) \to (y,x)$. My teacher told us to find out *what it is, what it is called, and why it is important?* Please help ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the general formula for translating graphs (or anything else placed on the coordinate axis) across the line y=x.  For example, you would mirror the point (4,3) across the line y=x to the point (3,4).

Comment: Translation is not the same as reflection.

Answer (score 0):

The [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28mathematics%29) of points on a plane (with coordinates $(x,y)$) across the [axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_of_symmetry) (in this case, the line described by the equation $y=x$) is just the [mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29) $(x,y)\to(y,x)$.  For example, the reflection (the [mirror image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_image)) of the point $(1,3)$ across the line $y=x$ is the point $(3,1)$.  (Click on the highlighted terms for more information.)

Answer (score 0):

This mapping creates the inverse relation (or inverse function, if the original is a bijective function).